# Can $\lambda_{\max}(AB)$ with $A$ orthogonal, can I be simplified?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If I have two matrices $A$ and $B$ and $A$ is orthogonal, can I make any simplifications to $\lambda_{\max}(AB)$? I think I can say $\lambda_{\max}(AB) = \lambda_{\max}(B)$ but I'm not sure exactly why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement is not correct as it can be seen in the next counterexample:

Define A orthogonal:
$ A=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0  \\ \end{array} \right)$ and let B be: $B=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
3 & 0 \\
0 & 1  \\ \end{array} \right)$. Then the max eigenvalue of B is 3, and the product AB has the two next eigenvalues: $\lambda_1=1.7321$ and $\lambda_2=-1.7321$, and so $\lambda_{max}(AB)\neq \lambda_{max}(B)$.

Answer (score 3):

If your matrices do not commute, the eigenvalues of $AB$ are not related in any simple way to the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$.  About all you can say is that $\det(AB) = \det(A) \det(B)$, where the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues (with algebraic multiplicities), and the determinant of an orthogonal matrix is $\pm 1$.